# XCODE 9.3.1 capabilities information

Tags: xcode

Where can I find the capabilities information in XCODE 9.3.1?

[XCODE CAPABILITIES TAB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5AoY.png)

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer, just change the Project to Target.

[Project name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDK6g.png)

[Change to "Target"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCWo0.png)